# Entity framework multiple rows insert issues

Tags: entity-framework

I have to add process CV files then add the data this will be multiple objects into database using EF

```
using (var db = new dbEntities())
{
    //Process CSV file

     foreach (AIRQ aqs in listairq)
          try
            {
              AIRQ aqs1 = new AIRQ();
              aqs1.FeatureID = aqs.FeatureID.Trim();
              aqs1.MeasurementDateTime = aqs.MeasurementDateTime;
              aqs1.ParameterID = aqs.ParameterID.Trim();
              aqs1.ParameterValue = aqs.ParameterValue;
              aqs1.Remarks = aqs.Remarks;
              db.AIRQTS.Add(aqs1);
              db.SaveChanges();

            }
              catch (Exception ex)
               {

                }
}
```

But i found though object **aqs1** is having different values but while calling   **db.SaveChanges();** it throws error primary key violation. An i saw the sql profile the values are different than object

Answer (score 0):

After troubleshooting I found when there is a record which already exists in database that throws error and it remains in collection list. So when loop runs again then while calling save changes it tries to insert again that previous record.

so in catch block i wrote

```
 db.AIRQUALITYTS.Remove(aqs);
 db.SaveChanges();
```